# Do users get a notification if I remove their permissions?

Tags: permissions, access, notifications

I am trying to clean up who all has permissions for the sub-sites of my SharePoint site I am the administrator of. We have been using SharePoint groups to grant users access, instead of granting individual access per user. When I go back to the Permissions page for the sub-site and Remove User Permissions for the selected users, do they get sent a notification of the change? If so, is there a way to prevent that notification from being sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not get a notice about permission removal, either from item scoped or group scoped permissions.

Comment: Great, thank you Trevor! I really appreciate the help

Comment: Don't forget to mark Trevor's response as the answer.